# How define jagged array in python

Tags: python, arrays, jagged-arrays

**Jagged array :** A multidimensional array that has lines of varying length
I also use C # cinnamon tooth arrays in Python. Is it possible?

```
int[][] jaggedArray = new int[3][];

jaggedArray[0] = new int[5]; jaggedArray[1] = new int[4]; jaggedArray[2] = new int[2];
```

Comment: In Python, you will typicall use a `list` object. Python containers (and in general) are heterogenous, you can put whatever type of object you want in them

Answer (score 2):

Just have a 2d array and fill it with zeros

```py
jaggedArray = [[] for row in range(3)]
'''
above line same as
jaggedArray = []
for row in range(3):
    jaggedArray.append([])
'''
jaggedArray[0] = [0]*5
jaggedArray[1] = [0]*4
jaggedArray[2] = [0]*2
print(jaggedArray)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
jaggedArray=list()
jaggedArray.append([0]*5)
jaggedArray.append([0]*4)
jaggedArray.append([0]*2)
```

This will create similar array that you have created in sample code.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a mutable data type for this, ie `list`

just create a list, define it's size if you want `list_ = [None for i in range(4)]`

and then with index you can add sublist inside it of any length like

```
list_[1] = [1,2,3,4,]
# list_ = [None, [1,2,3,4], None, None]
```

or you can create an empty list `list_ =[]`
and add the sublist using `append` operation like

```
list_.append([1,2,3])
#list_ = [[1,2,3]]
```

in later stage if you want to overwrite the sublist, you  can directly do that by assigning the index to new sublist ie `list_[2] = [1,2,3,]`